# I want to host my sveltekit SSR app to aws services ( Amplify) . How can we do that ? If we use adapter-static, will it affect the SSR?

Tags: deployment, aws-amplify, server-side-rendering, sveltekit, sveltekit-adapter-node

I want to host my sveltekit SSR app to aws services ( Amplify) . How can we do that ? If we use adapter-static, will it affect the SSR? If we can use any other aws services to host our sveltekit ssr web app, what are those?

I'm creating a project using sveltekit and I'm using SSR. I need to deploy this project to  AWS services.

Comment: I need help with similar situation!